# How to call ViewModel functions from AppWidgetProvider?

Tags: android, api, rest, mvvm, widget

I have an Retrofit2 API:

```
interface Api {
    @POST("/my/url")
    suspend fun function()
}
```

My ViewModel can call this HTTP function:

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val retrofiClient = APIClient.client!!.create(Api::class.java)

    fun test() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
                retrofitClient.function()
        }
    }
}
```

No problem when i call this from my activity.

But my goal is to call this test() function from my app's widget.
My basic AppWidgetProvider looks like this:

```
class AppWidgetProvider : AppWidgetProvider() {

    override fun onUpdate(
        context: Context,
        appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
        appWidgetIds: IntArray
    ) {
        // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this provider
        appWidgetIds.forEach { appWidgetId ->

            val intent = Intent()
            intent.action = "custom-event-name"
            intent.setClassName(
                MainActivity::class.java.getPackage().name,
                MainActivity::class.java.name
            )

            val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context.applicationContext,
                0,
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
            )
            val views: RemoteViews = RemoteViews(
                context.packageName,
                R.layout.appwidget
            ).apply {
                setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.test, pendingIntent)
            }

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val receiver: BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            println("INTENT RECEIVED")

        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        registerReceiver(receiver, IntentFilter("custom-event-name"))
        ...
    }
```

The  BroadcastReceiver does not receive the intent. Even if it does, can i call my app functions there?

How can i setup my app and/or widget, to call this viewModel.test() method when i click on a button in the widget?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Channel`(https://kotlinlang.org/docs/channels.html, for coroutines) or `RxRelay` (https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxRelay, for rxjava) instead of using broadcast receiver. Just put your `Channel` or `Relay` instance on your Application class so you can access it across your activities, fragments, etc.

Comment: Can you elaborate more, how the communication between widget and app works with channels`?

Comment: It's a same approach with Event Bus. You can put your channel in your application class. Then in your `AppWidgetProvider`, you pass app cntxt instead of contxt or pass app contxt along with contxt(wthever you prfer). So for example, from your widget you want to send data to your fragment, first observe your channel in your fragment something like (not exact code) `application.yourChannel.receiveAsFlow().onEach..` then when you want send data from your widget you can do `application.yourChannel.offer(dataYouWantToSend)`. So everytime you `offer`, it will be received on `receiveAsFlow.onEach`

Comment: or you can create a singleton/object class that will handle your channel instance (instead of putting it on application class)